# Writing SQL Query to query and update same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not very friendly with SQL so I need to write a SQL update/delete query on a table. The requirement is as below.

Table A:

Col1(PK)          Col2                                                 Col3                                                 Quantity

1                                                               Code1
                                Value1                                                5

2                                               Code2       Value2             2

3                 Code1         Value1            3

4                 Code3         Value3            8

Considering above table, in which there are multiple rows with same value for Col2 and Col3. I want to write a query which will delete duplicate combination of Col2 and Col3 and sum the Quantity for the resulting record.

The result should be like this:

Col1(PK)          Col2                                                 Col3                                                 Quantity

1                                                               Code1
                                Value1                                                8

2                                               Code2       Value2             2

4                 Code3         Value3            8

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do insert/update and delete in one query without using transactions or stored procedures. How do you run the queries (command line, server-side language ...)?

Comment: `I am not very friendly with SQL`, that made me giggle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do this in two parts, and if you want to ensure the integrity of the data, the two parts should be wrapped in a transaction.

The first part updates the required rows' `Quantity`, the second deletes the now duplicated rows.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE TableA
SET Quantity=upd.Quantity
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(Col1) AS Col1, SUM(Quantity)  AS Quantity
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY Col2, Col3 
) upd
ON a.Col1 = upd.col1

;WITH DELETES
AS
(
  SELECT Col1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col2,Col3 ORDER BY Col1) rn
  FROM TableA
)
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE Col1 IN (
    SELECT Col1 FROM DELETES WHERE rn>1
)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Live example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9efa9/7

(EDIT: Updated to fix issue noted in comments)

Comment: You speak the words which happened to be absent from my mouth.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the `DELETE` works?  It seems to be recursive.

Comment: will not work if you have more than two records having same value.

Comment: @sm.abdullah - can you explain a bit more what you think the problem is? The point of this was to delete columns with "two records having the same value". A demo explaining the problem using my sqlfiddle as a base would be best.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the `delete` is not recursive, it simply uses the form `DELETE FROM table WHERE col IN (1,2,3,4)` but using a select clause in the `IN`.

Comment: @Jamiec " multiple rows with same value for Col2 and Col3" not specific to Two. You are good with Two but not with multiple

Comment: @sm.abdullah - nothing ive written is specific to two rows that I can see. The first bit will aggregate up any number of rows into the min column. Once again, can you be a bit more explicit in what you're saying, a single sentence does not help this answer improve, and Im having a hard time understanding your point.

Comment: written a test case http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/daf670/1
you will see duplicate records.
you are deleting only the max records

Comment: Yep, I think I spotted the issue you were talking about. fixing now.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
  select *
    from (select *, sum(Quantity) over (partition by col2,col3) as Quantity
          from tableA
         ) t
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to just `SELECT` the result set you want into a new table, and then drop the previous table:

```
CREATE TABLE A_new(Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
                   Col2 varchar(255),
                   Col3 varchar(255),
                   Quantity INT);

INSERT INTO A_new (Col1, Col2, Col3, Quantity)
SELECT MIN(Col1) AS Col1, Col2, Col3, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM A
GROUP BY Col2, Col3
```

Next you can drop table `A` and rename `A_new` to `A`:

```
DROP TABLE A
sp_rename A_New, A
```

Comment: I dont have Create/DROP permission on DB.

Comment: I think @Mirceac21 is correct and a stored proc or transaction is the only hope here.

Comment: Drop/Create is not a good practice if you have a lage no of record in live DB.

Comment: As a one time event it is negotiable.

Answer (score 1):

For the first Update step(Assume that Table A has the name of Table_1)  :

```
Update Table_1 set Quantity = t.total 
from Table_1 As p inner join 
(select Min(Col1) as Col1,SUM(quantity) as total from Table_1 group by Col2,Col3) as t
on p.Col1=t.Col1
```

this will update each row that has more than 1 row with its SUM of quantity.

then you can delete the same row which its code2 has the same value with :

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT 
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Col2,Col3 ORDER BY Col2,Col3)
   FROM Table_1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1;
```

Sorry, I thought that Col2 would always be the same with Col3. *I have edited my statements. If you got more than 1 row, it could Delete all, except the first row.

Comment: Sample data:
Col1    Col2         Col3          Quantity
1          Code1      Value1     1<p>
2          Code2      Value2     1<p>
5          Code1      Value1     1<p>
4          Code3      Value3     1<p>
6          Code1      Value4     1

Comment: Why the delete statement is not working properly? its working perfectly fine in here. I have also created the identical table and tried it. Could you explain more?

Answer (score -1):

Please execute the below query:

```
SELECT 
    Col2,
    Col3,
    SUM(Quantity) 
FROM table_1
GROUP BY
    Col2,
    Col3
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and your query is on the right track.  Maybe you could explain your reasoning a bit more?

Comment: The question also asked about updating the table, this just selects the (admittedly, correct) data.

Comment: @Jamiec, I missed it. I was aware of jsfiddle site. From your answer, I knew about sqlfiddle site. Thanks!